# Animation in list item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

How to animate a listview row item on click. I want when I click on list item, an another list item view with some buttons should be animated over that particular list item. Is this possible.

Comment: custom dialog with list raised on item click will help

Answer (score -2):

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistview);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // write your animation code here
        // apply animation to the layout on which you 
        // want the animation to happen
    }
}
```